# FB Wall Posting with Link from FB IFrame App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall, spring-social

I am doing the FB Wall post with a link say http://www.rewardtv.com. When i post it from my standalone website (using spring social) the link on the wall is working fine. It goes to the rewardtv.com

But when i use the same code from FB app and post it to the wall, even though the wall post looks correct, but when i click on the link it is getting redirected to

http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=172622806174327&method=permissions.request&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rewardtv.com%2F&response_type=code&display=page&auth_referral=1

instead of rewardtv.com

and then getting a error page that my "An error occured with app name. Please try again.

Any help please... My intention is even if the wall posting is done from FB app (iframe), it should be directed to www.rewardtv.com instead of going to my app connect and permission

is there any extra permission need to granted in the app?

## Constructing link like below

```
   FacebookLink link  = new FacebookLink("http://www.rewardtv.com",
                rtvLinkTitle, rtvLinkHeading,
                rtvLinkMessage);
```

## and doing the post like

```
                   facebook.feedOperations().postLink(message, facebookLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

To rectify the problem follow the below steps,

To Post the Cross domain URL (http://www.rewardtv.com) as link do the following,

1. Go to developer app setting (https://developers.facebook.com/apps) for the corresponding App.
2. Click the Edit App tab.
3. Click the Advanced tab on left side.
4. In the settings of Migrations Menu, check the radio button to Disabled for Stream post URL security